# Issue on using an extension for GLSL when updating three.js

Tags: graphics, three.js, glsl

I'm currently upgrading three.js from a 2015 version, to the latest! However it seems that the GLSL shaders work in a slightly different manner. As a result, when trying to add an extension with `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` it seems to error and prevent the shader from being used. See below for the stack trace and the code pen for an example of the shader i'm using.

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
ERROR: 0:89: '
' : extension directive must occur before any non-preprocessor tokens in ESSL31: #version 300 es
```

https://codepen.io/redrubia/pen/ZEezjVw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to manually add `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` to your shader code. Instead, extensions can be managed over the material object. Please use this approach:

```js
material.extensions.derivatives = true;
```